# Firebase Deployed app producing 404 errors on img elements

Tags: firebase-hosting

I am hosting my images in an img folder within my app folder which is deployed to firebase. Everything is default for angularfire-seed project. However, I am getting 404 errors on all of my images? Any idea why? There is no access to the hosting for me to find out where my images are stored in firebase?

Firebase.json file:

```
{
    "firebase": "buddhagolfapp",
    "public": "app",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody comes looking for this... I was also cracking my head around the same problem. It turns out it takes a while for the images to load even after the firebase deploy command has returned the "successfully deployed" message, as there is some processing that needs to be done on their server.

See this link for more info https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/uBM64GHvfMc